# Matlab Edge Detection Function

Tags: matlab, function, edge-detection

I've got a task to create my own edge detection function using Matlab. But unfortunately, I've got no experience in image processing field, to the extent that I barely know how images are represented. Very little knowledge in this field.

I've read some papers and PDFs but they focus on many topics which I feel that I may not need them for my task.

I'd be happy to know your suggestions or if there is any particular paper, PDF, tutorial or quick guide for this purpose.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Every edge detection algorithm uses kernels like 3x3 matrix. As you can see below, **sobel_x** and **sobel_y** are called as [Sobel operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator). If you find **convolution of image and Sobel operator**, you will find the edges of image.

```
A=imread('motor.png'); % load image
A=rgb2gray(A); % convert to grayscale from rgb
A=im2double(A); % convert to double

sobel_x = [-1 0 1 ;... % define sobel operator of x axis 
           -2 0 2 ;...
           -1 0 1];...
sobel_y = [1 2 1;... % define sobel operator of y axis
           0 0 0;... 
           -1 -2 -1];

new_img_x=conv2(A,sobel_x); % convolution of image and sobel operator on x axis
new_img_y=conv2(A,sobel_y); % convolution of image and sobel operator on y axis

new_img=new_img_x+new_img_y; % sum two convolution

imshow(new_img); % show newly processed image
```